# How to disable "commandchars" in a "Verbatim" environment?

Tags: fancyvrb

How can I disable `commandchars` for a particular `Verbatim` environment, if I set it as a global option via `\fvset` earlier? I'm trying this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\fvset{commandchars=+\{\}}
\begin{document}
\begin{Verbatim}
Hello, +textbf{world}!
\end{Verbatim}
Now, I want to disable command chars:
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=]
Hello, +textbf{world}!
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

I'm getting:

```
! Improper alphabetic constant.
<to be read again>
                   \relax
l.9 \begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=]
```

Comment: try: `commandchars=none`

Comment: @DG' works fine, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `commandchars=none`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\fvset{commandchars=+\{\}}
\begin{document}
\begin{Verbatim}
    Hello, +textbf{world}!
\end{Verbatim}
Now, I want to disable command chars:
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=none]
    Hello, +textbf{world}!
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

[image]